# PostgreSQL error while commit/ rollback in function

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a Postgres function where I want to insert data into multiple tables and if any of them get failed then I want to rollback the transaction. But while writing the code begin transaction; in my function it says below error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "transaction"

Comment: Post your code...

Answer (score 1):

PL/PgSQL functions cannot begin or commit transactions.

You appear to want autonomous transactions, but they are not supported.

Perhaps you can do what you need with a PL/PgSQL `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION ...` block. You can abort the (sub)transaction with a `RAISE` command to raise an error, instead of `ROLLBACK`.